# Why ntpd -p times out?

Tags: time, ntp, timeout

Installed *ntpd* and everything works fine except

```
ntpdc -p localhost
```

I get

```
localhost: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

I check by issuing

```
systemctl status ntp
```

output shows, that the *ntpd* is running.

Could you show how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for mode 7 NTP packets used by `ntpdc` is no longer enabled by default; from the [official `ntpdc` documentation](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpdc.html):

> `ntpdc` is deprecated - please use `ntpq` now, as it uses a more sane interface and can provide all of the information that `ntpdc` used to provide.

If you *must* use `ntpdc` you have to enable mode 7 packets in your `ntp.conf`. See the [Command Index](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/comdex.html):

```
enable mode7
```

Be aware that the official documentation says that the flag `mode7`

> Enables processing of NTP mode 7 implementation-specific requests which are used by the deprecated `ntpdc` program. The default for this flag is disable. *This flag is excluded from runtime configuration using* `ntpq`. The `ntpq` program provides the same capabilities as `ntpdc` using standard mode 6 requests.

All the NTP [documentation](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/sitemap.html) can be accessed through the [NTP Public Services Project](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/WebHome) web page.